# What are the options to extend driveway (walking only)?

Tags: driveway

I'd like to extend driveway (area with red lines). The main purpose is to be able to walk there, so, it would be possible to park a car closer (and give more parking space in the rest of the driveway).

[image]

Quite new to such projects. A few naïve questions:

1. What are the options? Gravel, tiles, concrete, anything else? What are the pros and cons?
2. Is there a code I need to follow for such project?

Comment: Concrete or asphalt won't be a good choice unless you get rid of that tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to find out from your local municipality what code dictates that surface needs to be, if they care.  Often times that part of the driveway area (from sidewalk to street) is actually owned by the municipality, so you need to do what they'll allow.  Easiest/cheapest would be to dig down a few inches, tamp the dirt firm, put down some weed block and then a few bags of gravel from your local big-box store, then tamp again to firm up.  Anything else would just be more work/cost.

Comment: If the sidewalk at the edge of the image is a municipal sidewalk (as opposed, e.g., to a paved path from the driveway to front door), the OP is also going to run into trouble with their intended use of parking in the pictured portion of the driveway, as a vehicle parked in a position where the extension would be useful would also be obstructing the sidewalk.

Comment: You will kill the tree if you put in concrete, and there may be local protections for the tree.

Comment: @RLH, it will not be used for parking itself. The goal is to be able to part as close to asphalt edge as possible (and be able to walk from there) to free up a little bit of space in the rest of driveway.

Comment: @ZakiMa I get that. Is the concrete path at the right of the figure a path from your driveway to your door or a public sidewalk? If public, then it looks like parking adjacent to your proposed new paved section would obstruct the sidewalk.

Comment: @RLH, it is a path to my door...